# Simple markup field module

Tags: entities

I'm looking simple markup field (similar to [Field Hidden](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_hidden) which would provide dummy field which can place hold some html code (such as field title and its description without showing any field).

So basically something equivalent to this Form API element:

```
$form['markup'] = array('#markup' => '<span>foo bar</span>');
```

but as a proper field (so no custom coding or styling involved) which can be attached to Entityform.

Comment: ...otherwise known as a text field ;)

Comment: Oh wait, I misread. Would [Static field](https://www.drupal.org/project/static_field) do the job?

Comment: @Clive Yes, Static field should do the job I think. Thanks, I'll test it.

Comment: No worries - if it works will you put an answer in and accept it? I don't have time to test it to make sure it'll allow html

Comment: @Clive You can write an answer, and I'll accept it. I think it'll take me a while to test it yet, as I'm trying to do other stuff with entityforms meanwhile. But I'm sure it'll work:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174776/simple-markup-field-module?noredirect=1#comment210452_174776), there is a [Static field](https://www.drupal.org/project/static_field) which provides a static text that can be configured on a per instance basis via Field API.

Just enable the module and use Field UI to add and configure the field.

There is also another module, called: [Pseudo field](https://www.drupal.org/project/pseudo_field) which allows you to render an extra field as a real field (with field label).